# SQL Trouble Importing Data from .csv file

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, import

I am importing data in my database using SQL server, through excel .csv files. I right-click on the database I'm using, tasks, import data, go through the steps of selecting the file, choosing the destination:

[data source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkABe.png)
[image: destination]

going through the whole process, it says that all of my data has been imported successfully but when I check the table, there is no data.

Has anyone ever come across this? Or know of a reason as to why the data is not showing up in the table I have selected it to?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the error message you are getting from the wizard, assuming there is one?  Often, things will look completely OK, but at the very last step there will be a failure.  This could be due to a number of things, such as not having write access to the database.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That's the weird part, the import process looks like it's working fine, no error messages. I use `SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions (NULL, 'DATABASE');` to check permission and I get 78 rows with permission names.

Comment: I don't recognize your query as anything I have ever run.  What is that doing?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it returns three column entity name, subentity name, and permission_name. Permission_name lists permissions like:         
CREATE TABLE, CREATE VIEW, CREATE PROCEDURE ,CREATE FUNCTION, CREATE RULE, etc. Do you know any other reasons why the import process looks fine, but doesn't actually import?

Comment: I would have to see every step you took.  Are you certain the CSV file actually has data?

Comment: @drew10, What message column says "How many rows transferred?", After the import and export wizard gets successfully executed.

Comment: @MAK at the end of the import process, it says 1000 rows transferred; that is the correct number of rows that should've been transferred.

Comment: I just tried importing it again. The table I wanted to import it in was "source1" but the data imported into table "source1$". I'm not sure why.